# wp_cron schedulestops working after some period of time

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have set up a Wordpress cron job which is used to update/import posts on the website every day.

It takes a while and on localhost everything works perfectly, on the other hand after uploading the scripts on the server script stops working after some time.

Sometimes it updates 500 articles, sometimes 1k. 
Debug.log doesnt show anything specific, there are no errors like `script timeout` or `query limit exceeded` in there.

The script is just a foreach loop with set_time_limit for each iteration, reading contents of .csv and updating posts with it, it is run in wp_cron via include `scriptname.php`.

I understand this might be trivial, but I would appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: you said it not showing errors for this we need to troubleshoot this file on server side. may be any error occur.

Comment: You should use a real cron job for that. You're just upsetting visitors, because they have to wait until your job is done if they want to see your page...

Comment: Unfortunately i have no acces to ssh on the server tho it has to be done via wp_cron.

I can post the script and the server debug.log fileson dropbox if necessary.

Comment: show us the code ...